# How to check the bandwith that is used by each connection on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, bandwidth, connection, usage, bandwidth-measuring

I am trying to get stats on how much of a bandwidth each connection uses on Apache?

I have Apache 2.4 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. I would like to know how many users more I can add on my existing environment. I would like to calculate the average connection.

Also, what other information that can help me make a decision on how many more users I can add on my existing system.

Answer (score 0):

Each apache log entry contains the number of bytes sent in that request:

```
192.168.3.232 - - [08/Jul/2013:15:18:58 -0500] "GET /munin/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1686 "http://10.100.0.10/munin/example.com/memory.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"
```

The number following the `200` response code is the number of bytes transmitted.

It's a trivial process to parse out that field and sum up the entries associated with your "average connection".

> Also, what other information that can help me make a decision on how
>   many more users I can add on my existing system.

You'll need to collect performance data for all of the basic hardware resources your server uses: CPU, Memory, Disk, etc.

Comment: which file would I need to look at access.log or ssl_request.log? and how can I parse the file since the files are too big.

Comment: You look in whatever file contains the desired log entries. You'll need to look at your apache configuration for that. In regards to parsing the file, that's a completely different question, and something that you should research a bit. It can be done easily using standard CLI tools that you already have access to.